# Bean Creation Exception, Entity Manager Factory error

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I'm going to run `eatgoAdminApiApplication` and it works.
but, when I input `application.yml` then it doesn't work.
I tried many things after I searched for this problem and all didn't work.
Unfortunately, error messages were too long, so I cut some of them out.
My code: https://github.com/Junga-a/Restaurant-Reservation-site.git
Error Messages:

```
2021-01-02 02:42:37.012 ERROR 6464 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Wrong user name or password [28000-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:461) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:340) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:173) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:152) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.lambda$h2Console$0(H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.java:73) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider.ifAvailable(ObjectProvider.java:93) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.h2Console(H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.java:72) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:625) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:202) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:96) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:85) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:253) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:227) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at ...



Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Wrong user name or password [28000-200]

Add username and password to your data source configuration.
Precise JDBC driver and hibernate dialect also.

```
spring:
datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: XXXX
    username: USERNAME
    password: PASSWORD     
jpa:
    database: H2
    show-sql: false
```

If you are working in a real application, use a database serve (Mysql, Postgresql...)
H2 is a file or a memory database, it cannot handle transactions :-).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Your code works well. But if I add hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update <<then it don't work again. I don't know what is wrong. Plus, if I enter code "http POST localhost:8080/restaurants name="Bob zip" address=Seoul" in terminal, error commits again. It says "Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection". I need yout help.

Comment: I checked out the GitHub code, there are a lot of compilation errors. I can't run it.
Just a piece of advice, use DTO and a relational database, don't mix prod and test configurations, create a separate YAML for your test configuration.
I need to see the complete stack trace or to run the program to be able to help you. Fix the compilation issues :-).